# unable to connect asp.net application with godaddy.com sql server database

Tags: asp.net, connection-string

I have domain on the godaddy.com. I have create the database over there.I am able to connect to the database from godaddy.com site with specified user name and password. but when i am going to use same information in my connection string in my asp.net web application on local machine it is showing

```
"A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while establishing a connection
```

to SQL Server. The server was not found or was not accessible. Verify that the instance

name is correct and that SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections. (provider:

Named Pipes Provider, error: 40 - Could not open a connection to SQL Server)"

This error. 
my connectionstring is :

```
<add name="MyConnectionString" 
             connectionString="Data Source=myDataSource; Initial Catalog=MyDatabaseName; User ID=MyUserId; Password=MyPassword" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
```

I have provided all required parameters to connection string here.I got this parameter information from godaddy.com database Description section.

Answer (score 0):

You can't do that, their SQL server don't accept external connections.

[EDIT] OK, it seems that my first sentence is incorrect, look here:

http://community.godaddy.com/help/article/4978

http://community.godaddy.com/groups/web-hosting/forum/topic/ms-sql-remote-access/

http://help.godaddy.com/article/4977

Comment: but i could able to do same with my another application, with same domain. Even i am using its connection string format now also.